# How to disable the Long-Press event of Action Bar menu Item?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In Android, I Have created an action bar and added few menus item to it.  When I click menu items, I am performing some action.

On long click I find a empty toast message.   My Question is how to disable the toast on long click?

Answer (score 5):

Instead trying to disable the empty "toast like" view, you may add the "android:title" attribute to describe what's the action actually do.

Example:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/action_websearch"
      android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_websearch"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

Comment: This shows the correct text for me, but not in a very good display.  Any idea how to style that toast message?  I've been looking for a way, but had no luck.

Comment: I'm using appcompat library and creating the toolbar using setSupportActionBar(toolbar), somehow the toast message does not show on long press even after I set the title and showAsAction to ifRoom|withText just like your example. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

in menu_add_key layout refer to a custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tumblr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menuAddKey"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/item_addkey"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title=""/>

</menu>
```

define your item_addkey layout as you want

and in java code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_add_key, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.menuAddKey).getActionView().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                showAddKeyDialog("");
            }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the long click on a menu item:

```
menu.findItem(R.id.menuAddKey).getActionView()  return null
```